# Halving a discrete random variable?

Tags: random-variable

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable taking its values in $\mathbb{N}$. I would like to *halve* this variable, that is, to find a random variable $Y$ such as:

$$X = Y + Y^*$$

where $Y^*$ is an independent copy of $Y$.

- I am referring to this process as *halving*; this is a made-up terminology. Is there a proper term found in the literature for this operation?
- It looks to me that such $Y$ always exists only if we accept negative probabilities. Am I correct in my observation?
- Is there a notion of best *positive* fit for $Y$? Aka the random variable that would be the "closest" to solve the equation above.

Thanks!

Comment: In the cases where you can't "halve" exactly, there are multiple possible definitions of "closest"; it depends on what you want to optimize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A notion strongly related to this property (if weaker) is [decomposability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution). A decomposable law is a probability distribution that can be represented as the distribution of a sum of two (or more) non-trivial independent random variables. (And an indecomposable law cannot be written that way. The "or more" is definitely irrelevant.) A necessary and sufficient condition for decomposability is that the characteristic function $$\psi(t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp\{itX\}]$$ is the product of two (or more) characteristic functions.

I do not know whether or not the property you consider already has a name in probability theory, maybe linked with [infinite divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29). Which is a much stronger property of $X$, but which includes this property: all infinitely divisible rv's do satisfy this decomposition.

A necessary and sufficient condition for this "primary divisibility" is that the root of the characteristic function $$\psi(t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp\{itX\}]$$ is again a characteristic function.

In the case of distributions with integer support, this is rarely the case since the characteristic function is a polynomial in $\exp\{it\}$. For instance, a Bernoulli random variable is not decomposable.

As pointed out in the [Wikipedia page on decomposability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution), there also exist absolutely continuous distributions that are non-decomposable, like the one with density$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\{-x^2/2\}$$

In the event the characteristic function of $X$ is real-valued, [Polya's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions) can be used:

> **Pólya’s theorem.** If φ is a real-valued, even, continuous function which satisfies the conditions
>
> ```
> φ(0) = 1,
> φ is convex on (0,∞),
> φ(∞) = 0,
> ```
>
> then φ is the characteristic function of an absolutely continuous
>   symmetric distribution.

Indeed, in this case, $\varphi^{1/2}$ is again real-valued. Therefore, a sufficient condition for $X$ to be primary divisible is that φ is root-convex. But it only applies to symmetric distributions so is of much more limited use than [Böchner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner's_theorem) for instance.

Answer (score 6):

There are some special cases where this holds true, but for an
*arbitrary* discrete random variable, your "halving" is not possible.

- The sum of two independent Binomial$(n,p)$ random variables is a
  a Binomial$(2n,p)$ random variable, and so a Binomial$(2n,p)$ can be
  "halved".
  Exercise: figure out whether a Binomial$(2n+1,p)$ random variable can be "halved".
- Similarly, a Negative Binomial$(2n,p)$ random variable can be "halved".
- The sum of two independent Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variables is a Poisson$(2\lambda)$; conversely, a Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variable is the sum of two independent Poisson$(\frac{\lambda}{2})$ random
  variables.  Indeed, as @Xi'an points
  out in a comment, a Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variable can be "halved" as many times
  as we like: for each positive integer $n$,
  it is the sum of $2^n$ independent 
  Poisson$\left(\frac{\lambda}{2^n}\right)$ random variables.

Comment: +1 My recollection is that the discrete uniform is a particular case where it's not possible (I believe there are numerous others, but it's one I have looked at).

Comment: Indeed, a uniform distribution is decomposable but not divisible in the above sense.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is one example of an infinitely divisible distribution, so can be divided in a sum of an arbitrary number of iid variates.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to me that you ask for an "independent copy", otherwise you could just multiply with $\frac{1}{2}$? Instead of writing copy (a copy is always dependent), you should maybe write "two independent, but identically distributed random variables".

To answer your questions,

- what comes closest is maybe the term convolution. For given $X$, you are looking for two iid RV with convolution $X$.
- if you accept negative probabilities, these are no longer random variables, since there is no probability space anymore. There are cases where you can find such $Y,Y^*$ ($X$ $\lambda$-Poisson-distributed, $Y$,$Y^*$ $\frac{\lambda}{2}$-Poisson-distributed), and cases where it is not possible ($X$ Bernoulli, as example).
- i haven't seen any, and i can't imagine how to formalize such a *best* fit. Usually, approximations to random variables are measured by a norm on the space of random variables. I can't think of approximations of random variables by or to non - random variables.

I hope i could help.